# Can not display website with WebView Component in Xamarin Forms on Andriod Emulator

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, mobile, xamarin.forms

I want to display an browser inside of my application that I am creating in Xamarin Forms. I am using WebView component to achieve this and the only websites that I can display are https://google.com, https://mtv.com and https://github.com. I can not display https://facebook.com OR **https://app.powerbi.com/home** which the link that I want to actually show. Some work in https and some don't.

I have tried everything...

```
**CODE FOR XAML FILE**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
x:Class="ACTMobile.Views.DetailViews.ConnectivityDashboardScreen"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button
            Clicked="Back_Clicked"
            HeightRequest="40"
            Text="&lt;"
            WidthRequest="40" />
        <Button
            Clicked="Forward_Clicked"
            HeightRequest="40"
            Text="&gt;"
            WidthRequest="40" />
        <Entry x:Name="url" WidthRequest="180" />
        <Button
            Clicked="Go_Clicked"
            HeightRequest="40"
            Text="Go"
            WidthRequest="50" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Label
        x:Name="LoadingLabel"
        IsVisible="false"
        Text="Loading" />
    <WebView
        x:Name="Browser"
        HeightRequest="1000"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Navigated="Handle_Navigated"
        Navigating="Handle_Navigating"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        WidthRequest="1000" />
</StackLayout>
```

```
** CODE FOR CS FILE **
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ACTMobile.Views.DetailViews
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ConnectivityDashboardScreen
{
    public ConnectivityDashboardScreen()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        url.Text = "https://www.xamarin.com";
        Browser.Source = url.Text;
    }

    void Handle_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadingLabel.IsVisible = false;
    }

    void Handle_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadingLabel.IsVisible = true;
    }

    void Go_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Browser.Source = url.Text;
    }

    void Forward_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Browser.CanGoForward)
            Browser.GoForward();
    }

    void Back_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Browser.CanGoBack)
            Browser.GoBack();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did it work fine in iOS device?

Comment: I have not tried it on an iOS device. I found the problem and it was the corporate proxy blocking.